# How to send file using ajax file upload to controller along with other parameters like textbox data in spring mvc?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

Also need to send data in json to server side with file. how to handle this on server and client side?

Comment: Didn'n get you? You need to upload file on server using ajax and also want to send some json data in that ajax call ??

Comment: hey for sending data you can use following library
http://zurb.com/playground/ajax-upload

Comment: Along with the user selected file i need to send  some parameters(values of textboxes entered by user) to server side? so how to do both simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

[image]As I know you can send just text with an file and not in JSON format or an binary file.
You can check them all with postman!
There is one Controller example in backend:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImageGallery", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<JPresent<Boolean>> imageGallery(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                                      @RequestParam("marketerId") Long marketerId) {

        Boolean result = new Boolean(false);

        MarketerPictureModel pictureModel = new MarketerPictureModel();
        byte[] bytes;
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                pictureModel.setContentType(file.getContentType());
                service.addToImageGallery(pictureModel);
                return jpresent.getResponse(result = true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return ...
            } catch (Exception e) {
            ...

    }
```